# CSS - Keep the parent expanded and sub menu highlighted when clicked on the submenu.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a CSS Vertical menu with submenus. I have added this in an ASP.Net application in the master page. Each menu click navigates to a different aspx pages. When any of submenu inside the expanded parent menu is clicked, the page is redirected to the respective aspx page , but the parent collapses again and does not retain the sub menu higlighted. I want the parent menu to be expanded and the submenu clicked to be highly.

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function() {

        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {

            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {

            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

HTML

```
<div id="cssmenu" >
                    <ul >
                        <li class="highlight">
                            <a  id="upload" href="Upload.aspx" ><span>Upload</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li >
                            <a id="home" href="Home.aspx" ><span>Home</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='Configurable Parameters.aspx'><span>configurable Parameters</span></a>
                        </li>
                    <li class='active has-sub'>
                        <a href='#'><span>Input</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class='last'>
                                    <a  href="#"><span>Data - QRM</span></a>
                                </li>

                                <li class='last'>
                                    <a href="DMSwaps.aspx"><span>Data Murex - Swaps</span></a>
                                </li>  
                                <li class='last'>
                                    <a href="DMMRates.aspx"><span>Data Murex - Market rates</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class='last'>
                                    <a href="#"><span>Data - Previous Months</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class='active has-sub'>
                        <a href='#'><span>DF Rate</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class='last'>
                                    <a href='#'><span>DF Rate - Prospective</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class='last'>
                                    <a href='#'><span>DF Rate - RetroProspective</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Designation</span></a></li>
                    <li class='active has-sub'>
                        <a href='#'><span>Regression Analysis</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class='last'>
                                    <a href='#'><span>Regression Test Prospective</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class='last'>
                                    <a href='#'><span>Regression Test - RetroProspective</span></a>


                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Fair Valuation</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>benchmark calculation hedged item</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Test Result</span></a> </li>
                            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Delta FV</span></a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Amortisation</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Amortisation</span></a> </li>
                            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Reverse Amortisation</span></a> </li>
                            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Amortisation, if hedge is ineffective</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Output</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Accounting Entries</span></a> </li>
                            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Infor Next Period</span></a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Reports</span></a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
 #cssmenu {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
 line-height: 1;
 width: 250px;
 } 
 .align-right {
  float: right;
 }
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
    }
  #cssmenu ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

    }
    #cssmenu ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
        }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
      color: #00802b;
       text-transform: uppercase;
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      border-top: 1px solid #00802b;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  background:url("../images/img04.gif")  ; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 650;
  -webkit-transiton: all 0.25s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
   transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px;

        }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu > ul > li.open > a,
        #cssmenu > ul {
        background-image: url(../images/content_grey.jpg);
        color: white; nu_button.jpg) repeat-x;
        }
    #cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
      content: ""; 
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 13px solid #00802b;
  border-botom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -13px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
 #cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 13px solid #151515;
  border-botom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -12px;
  bottom: -1px;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #dddddd;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 20px;
  top: 24.5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#cssmenu ul > li:hover::after,
#cssmenu ul > li.active::after,
#cssmenu ul > li.open::after {
  border-top-color: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a::after {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: -13px;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a::before {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: -12px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  color: #777777;
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  padding-top: 18px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li {
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #e4e4e4;
  color: #666666;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  border-top: 13px solid #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a::before {
  border-top: 13px solid #e4e4e4;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub::after {
  top: 18.5px;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-top-color: #777777;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover::after,
#cssmenu ul ul > li.active::after,
#cssmenu ul ul > li.open::after {
border-top-color: #666666;
}
```

Comment: [check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/Renison/t8y4kn0m/) I added a background color on click.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rex. But my problem is different. I want to retain the selection and keep the menu expanded when the submenu is clicked.  For example, if i click on the data murex swaps in the Input menu, the murex swaps page should be loaded and the selection should be retained. currently, the menu is getting collapsed during page load.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you reload the page, all changes you make to the DOM are lost. One option would be to, upon page load, check all of you `a` elements' `href` attributes against the current path. If there is a match, then you could apply your 'opening' logic. The code would look roughly like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href') == location.pathname.substr(1))
            {
            //apply your 'open' logic here
            }
    });

    //....Other code
});
```

*Note: this code works if your links are only relative paths without query strings, and without the leading `/` character (which which is how they appear in your question). If they are absolute, have query strings, or have the leading `/` you'll have to do some string processing before the plain `$(this).attr('href') == location.pathname.substr(1)` comparison in my answer.